# Задача с равенством в Си

Tags: c

Столкнулся с такой задачей:

```
/*Тут что-то должно быть*/
if (a == a)
   printf("y");
else 
   printf("n");
```

В поле где комментарий можно что-то написать, чтобы вывелось "n" нигде решения я найти не смог, как это может работать?

Comment: `#include <math.h> ... float a = NAN;`

Comment: `#define  a 1,0`

Comment: @Harry, нужно именно внутри мейна, с подключенной только stdio.h

Comment: @wololo нужно именно внутри мейна, с подключенной только stdio.h

Comment: `float a = 0.0f / 0;`

Comment: И что? Пишите внутри `main` - какая разница? https://ideone.com/ahxtpI

Comment: @wololo, так не компилируется

Comment: @Harry, не знал, что так можно, спасибо)

Comment: `volatile float tmp = 0; float a = 0 / tmp;`

Comment: Кстати, а вы извлеките урок, что писать нужно **полный** вопрос, а не начинать потом рассказывать, что неверно в ответе. В вопросе вы ничего не говорили о том, что "нужно именно внутри мейна, с подключенной только stdio.h"...